# Use the title value as text inside a dialog

Tags: jquery

I have been having massive issue getting a value passed into my dialog.  I have managed to get it there as the title.  This value is an ID which I plan to use in a query  which will get the content for the dialog. How can I use this value to print onscreen in the dialog (and use in my query)  Here is how I populate the .title:

```
function openDialog1() { // called by the inner iframe
$('#dialog1').dialog({
    show: "fold",
    hide: "explode",
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: $('#dialog1').data('v'),
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }

});
}
```

and here is where I would like to use the value which is showing nicely as my title:

```
    <div id="dialog1" >

   the id is ???   ...
</div>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: So you get the ID from somewhere else and you want to print it where the `???` are show ?

Comment: I want to print the value in the .title property which which has taken me forever to get into the dialog!  Its showign in the title but I want to use it again in two ways.  Print it inside the <div> and use it in an SQL statement in the div

Comment: So what do you want now ? Take the title value from the dialog and use it, right ?

Comment: Yes EG inside my div say your ID is title.value is there a way to do this?

Comment: All I can think of now is making a function that will change the text of your div, the text will use the title.value, I don't know if that suites you, does it ?

Comment: I would like the content of the div to be dynamic based on the value it has taken me hours to get into the title.value - Any way you can think of me being able to use this would be helpful.  Can you assist. I have been banging my head against a wall for hours on this, what ever works suits me.  I fairly sure you must understand  my issue?

Answer (score 0):

It think the best option is to hook into the [jQuery dialog's `open` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) and modify the HTML of the dialog there, something like this:

```
$('#dialog1').dialog({
    show: "fold",
    hide: "explode",
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: $('#dialog1').data('v'),
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $('#dialog1').html('the id is ' + $('#dialog1').data('v'));        
    },
    buttons: {
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: Great that has allowed me to print the value inside the dialog, thank you.  I want to query the database and get some content for it how can I access this value from inside the div so I can use it in an sql statement?

Comment: You should just be able to get the value from reading `$('#dialog1').data('v')`, I don't think you'll need to read it out of the `div`. Or you can read out the dialog's title after it has been initialized like this: `var title = $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "option", "title" );`

Comment: I would like to write an sql query inside the div this is why I want to use this value inside the div EG I cant say SELECT * from tble where ID=$('#dialog1').data('v') - SO, is there a way to use this value in such a way from inside the div?

Comment: Try: `var query = 'SELECT * from tble where ID=' + $('#dialog1').data('v')`. Now the `query` variable will hold the SQL query. How to use this query to get data from a database and stick the values into the dialog is a totally different matter, and it involves a lot more than just jQuery.

Comment: I am using ASP for the database/server side of things, this is the easy part...   I understand what you are suggesting by building th query and using the $('#dialog1').data('v') up in the jquery but I still have the same issue.  How to use the new 'query' inside the div?  Am I not asking my questions very well when I say how can I use a jquery value inside the div to do things with?

Comment: Yes it is not clear to me what you mean by "inside the div". You'll need to call a JavaScript function somewhere to get anything done, if this is from somewhere "inside the div" or not is besides the point. Inside any JavaScript function you could read that title value by reading out `$('#dialog1').data('v')`. You could add another button and hook a JavaScript function to it: `buttons: { GetMyQuery: function () { var query = 'SELECT * from tble where ID=' + $('#dialog1').data('v'); }}`. Then you just have to add some code which executes the query and does something with the result.

Comment: OK I will need to re-think the way I am trying to achieve this I think.  As you can figure I am a relative jquery novice.  You have been very helpful.  Thank you for your time and effort, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attr` function to take the value of the title and add it to your text, suppose your HTML is this :

```
<div id="dialog"> 
     <p>my ID is :</p>
     <button id="showID">show ID</button>
</div>
```

I'd use a script that allows rewriting the text of the `<p>` tag :

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
                        show: "fold",
                        hide: "explode",
                        width: 500,
                        height: 500,
                        title: "voila",
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Close: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }    
                    });

    $('#showID').click(function(){
                        var title = $('#dialog').attr('title') ;
                        $('#dialog p').text('my ID is :' + title);
                    });
```

Comment: Hi there - I tried using this however the value of the title dos not print anywhere inside the div.  Obviously a button shows (which I dont want)  It seems so simple, clearly its not. Would very much appreciate any other thoughts you may have.  I think I have been super clear in what I want to achieve?